# How do I troubleshoot a member who is unable to log in?

Tags: members, login

I have a member who can't log into my site via a log in form in a template (not accessing the control panel). He has tried two accounts off the same computer, I can access the site using his account. He doesn't get any feedback after logging in like he's using the wrong password, etc. The page just reloads like he did nothing. I'm not sure how to figure out what the problem is.

I've asked him to clear his cache and cookies and restart, which he has done. I've asked him to download and try using Firefox or Chrome instead of Safari to see if it's a problem with his browser, which I'm getting the feeling is asking too much of him. I have had no problems with the other 25 members who have accessed the site.

A little bit about the set up. I have all the access settings for most of the site set to "no access" for guests with my login page as the template that loads if the person is not logged in. So I think it's not finding anything wrong with his login credentials, hence no errors, but hitting some issue to logging him in and then loads the login page again.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Update: I now have two users who can't log in on this system. They are both using Safari in OS X 10.7.5. The user I mentioned is having no issues in Chrome, so I'm chalking it up to the browser. I'd like to figure out what is causing the problem, and either fix it or contribute a bug error. I really don't like asking users to download another browser when they are using Safari. That seems like a lame 'fix' to me.

Comment: Update: Asking for basic information from users is like pulling teeth. I found a web site where a visitor can send a developer a lot of info about how they are browsing the web: http://www.whatismybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think his browser has to accept cookies.

Francois

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good thing to ask!

Comment: I am thinking more and more that it has to be cookie related. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

What EE version are you running?
Earlier versions had a problem where if a user was on IPv6, they couldn't log in. This was fixed in later versions.

If he's on IPv6 and you are running an old EE install, you may need to update.

Comment: Can you tell in which version this was fixed? When the problem started I was on 2.6, and hadn't updated because I was unsure how my extensive use of safecracker would work. After changing all those tags to the new forms tag in the template, I have upgraded the system to 2.7, but the member still can't log in.

Comment: [2.5.1](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.5.1-released) - I guess that wasn't the answer.